# Do I have to recompile something if I add a new route to a laravel nova component?

Tags: laravel-nova

After near 5 years of using Nova, and near 1 year of developing custom components for Nova, I am starting to suspect I am not using the right tool. I am already learning FilamentPHP.
Anyways, to the point.

I have a nova custom component on a project running smoothly. I tried to re-use exactly the same one by just adding a couple of new routes in the component api.php. However, those new routes do not even appear when running a "php artisan route:list".

So my question is the one in the title. Am I missing something? I tried already to run an npm run dev, composer dump-autoload, cleared caches, etc.
Thanks in advance